# Spaces between bootstrap labels get removed when created on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on my button **create** it creates a new bootstrap label each time.

But when it does there is no gap as you can see in the image below the labels are bunched up.

[image]

Question How can I make it so when I click my create button the labels will have the space between them. jQuery seems to remove the space.

> [**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/aJaQLd)

```
$(document).on("click", "#tag", function(event) {
  $('.label-container').append('<div class="label label-default">Default</div>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="label-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" id="tag" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a margin to your labels.

In your CSS:

```
.label {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for that is missing is that `inline-block` will generally render a gap for whitespace between `inline-block` elements-- for instance, if you create those elements in markup with lines between them, it will include a small gap.  However, the `append` method adds no whitespace, and as such the elements are directly adjacent.

While I agree with amallard's solution of handling this with CSS, if you really want to recreate the affect of how it looks when written into HTML, you could simply include a small amount of whitespace (like a single space) in your `append`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tag", function(event) {
  $('.label-container').append('<div class="label label-default">Default</div> ');
});
```

Comment: Wow, didn't knew it. Spot on !!

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird/surprising little "gotcha" in CSS behavior-- most of the time people are trying to figure out [how to get rid of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) rather than add it back :)  It's a "good-to-know" kind of thing so that you recognize it when it pops up on you.